# button1_Click = button1_Click_1

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am creating a windows forms app in VB. I clicked on the button to create a click event and it created a button1_Click.

I then clicked the button again to get into the subroutine again and it created a second click event called button1_Click_1.

Previously it just put my cursor back into the first button click event but now its creating a new instance of it.

Any ideas?

VS2022

Thanks in advance!

I was expecting it to just go into the first click event?

Comment: Pls. show the code which you tried

Comment: @Blackcat looks to me like a question about the IDE and form designer, not code.

Comment: @craig I am confused, `get into the subroutine` I thought to execute the click event.

Comment: @Blackcat see the answer from Brett Whittaker.  I think in this context "get into the subroutine" means to go from the form designer to the coded event handler, all at design time.

Comment: @craig Then click in the text as a text editor. Is it not working?

Comment: One way to make this scenario happen is if you CUT (Ctrl-X) the Button, then PASTED it somewhere else on the form. When you "cut" it disconnects the click handler. Then the next time you double click it wants to use the original name but sees that it already exists in the code and creates a new method for the handler by adding the "_1" on the end.

Answer (score 1):

button1_Click or button1_Click_1 is not important, its just sub name

```
Handles button1.Click
```

Determines where to focus

```
 Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description it sounds like you are trying to use the IDE form designer as a navigation aid (short-cut) to reach the code-behind event associated with the button object on your form.

The first time you clicked the button dropped onto your form within the IDE, it auto-generated **button1_Click**.  Then you observed that when you clicked on it a second time, the IDE auto-navigated back to the code-behind associated with the button.  Then the event must have been disconnected from the control, and when you click again **button1_Click_1** would result.

In my experience with the IDE a new event called **button1_Click_1** would only get generated if the original **object(button) -> event** was disassociated but the code behind was not cleaned-up, so it appends the _1 and creates **button1_Click_1**.

Everyone will have their own preferred style of working, but generally my personal preference is to avoid clicking on objects within the IDE form designer and prefer to use the "properties window" of the desired control (in this case a button) to create/update/remove associated event relationships.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because the button event is disconnected from the processing method.

You can check the **Events** option in the **Properties** window of **Button1** and reset the handling method of the **Click** event to **button1_Click**, or manually add `Handles button1.Click` after the `Private Sub button1_Click (sender As Object, e As EventArgs)`.